# How to get Principal object in ModelAttribute method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to load some basic user information that should be available for every HTTP request. I read that I can do this with a @ControllerAdvice class with a @ModelAttribute method. For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultController{

  @ModelAttribute
  public void load(ModelMap model){


  }

}
```

However, I am having trouble accessing my Principal object managed by Spring Security. I have tried the following:

```
  @ModelAttribute
  public void load(ModelMap model, @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser user){


  }
```

and

```
  @ModelAttribute
  public void load(ModelMap model, Principal user){
  //Cast to CustomUser object

  }
```

But both of these do not work. I am getting nulls for the user objects. I was wondering if anyone knew how to get the Principal object in @ModelAttribute methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized that when visiting my homepage for the first time, the user isn't authenticated so there wouldn't be a user object in spring security anyway.

I just needed to check if the object is null first like so

```
@ModelAttribute
public void load(ModelMap model, @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser user){

 if(user != null){
    long userId = user.getId();
    //Query database with userId and add data to model
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get an `Authentication` object using `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder`

```
@ModelAttribute
public void addUserToModel(Model model) {
    try {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String username = auth.getName();
        // do something
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
}
```

In fact, you can use `SecurityContextHolder` from anywhere in your application.